# Not possible to use Bluethooth Headset with A2DP (High Fidelity) and Microphone simultaneously

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone, headset

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 with Gnome shell.

Is it possible to connect a bluethooth headset (Sony MDR-ZX770BN) but not to set High Quality (A2DP) inside Pulse Audio Control and put on the microphone simultaneously?

Every time I switch to the microphone of the headset the quality of the speakers changes to low-quality (HSP/HFP).

How can I switch A2DP on and make the microphone work together?

Comment: I had the same problem and after a lot of research I realized that this is not supported by the A2DP protocol. A2DP only supports either output, or input, but not both simultaneously.

Comment: There must be some workaround here.  Using the same bluetooth headphones on a chromebook gives great quality audio and the mic works!

Comment: I think it's a bug of Pulseaudio because on Windows or Android it works out of box.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything i possibly could, ofono and phonesim too. But i couldn't use the microphone of my headset. So i discovered another way to use a mic.

All you need is an Android phone which has bluetooth.

Firstly, go to google playstore on your phone and download a bluetooth microphone app.

I used this one (Simple Bluetooth Mic): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.google.chrischan.simplebluetoothmic

Alternatively, you can use this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wimlog.com.myandroidtest4.

Connect the phone's bluetooth to your PC.

Now connect your bluetooth headset to the PC. (Both the devices must be connected simultaneously)

Open the Simple Bluetooth Mic App on your phone, click on speak.

Voila, that's it.

Basically you are using your phone's mic, because we can't use the bluetooth headset for both audio input and output.(even if it works for you, changing from A2DP to HSP everytime you need to use the headset mic is ughhh)

If this doesn't work, go to your sound settings and choose the input device as your phone's bluetooth.

HOPE THIS HELPS :)

Answer (score 0):

This "problem" is implicit bluethooth (BT) profiles by design:

[a2dp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_(A2DP))-> hd audio, no input

[HSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Headset_Profile_(HSP))/[HFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Hands-Free_Profile_(HFP)) -> low audio with input

There is no profile with hd audio with input.
The limit is the throughput of bluethooth.
a2dp uses the full throughput for hd audio output (device 2 headphones)
HSP/HFP uses half for playing audio half for mice (device 2 head set,head set 2 device)

someone created a script for linux to swich between the two:

[How to keep the audio profile at A2DP while using a mic with Bluetooth headset? (Push-to-talk)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004712/how-to-keep-the-audio-profile-at-a2dp-while-using-a-mic-with-bluetooth-headset)

His script shared on github:
https://gist.github.com/OndraZizka/2724d353f695dacd73a50883dfdf0fc6

the situation **[my be different with BT 5](https://www.amarinfotech.com/differences-comparisons-bluetooth-5-vs-4-2.html)**, but would need BT 5 on both ends  device and head set. BT 5 has a bigger throughput witch **could** enable hd audio and mic at the same time, but i was unable to find anything on that regart

My understanding is that some proprietary extensions provide the needed functionality. Ex.: [aptX Voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AptX#aptX_Voice) uses an advanced codec to provide better audio and mice support...